SWIM on STM8 does not respond on activation sequence by synchronization frame
I'm trying to work make SWIM activation sequence for STM8 by external microcontroller of another company.
I use timing diagram from UM0470

In phase 4 STM8 should respond to host by keeping swim pin LOW for 128 HSI cycles having frequency about 8MHz (about 16 microseconds overall). But STM8 does not respond.
I checked timings by oscilloscope and in phase 1 duration of low level keeping is 16 us, pulses in phase 2 are 500 us and 250 us (semiperiods of 1 KHz and 2 KHz respectively). For final negative impulse I've tried 500us and 250 us and it did not matter. For phase 3 I tried durations of 350 ns, 800 ns and 1 us (according to UM0470 it must be at least 300 ns). Voltage levels correspond to that is written in STM8 Datasheet.
What may be the cause of this problem and how to resolve it?

I am doing something similar now, but with an incircuit tester.
Some things to try:

for section 3, are you driving the SWIM pin high, or are you setting your external micro controller pin to hich Z, and letting the pullup pull the pin high?
in my opinion, the low period after the 4th 2 kHz pulse should be 250u based on figure 5.
after pulling the SWIM low for ~16us, Figure 4 has the SWIM line going high then low for an indeterminate amount of time. Maybe its high for 1000uS, then low for 500uS. did you ensure to include that in your setup?

I will update this post if / when I am successful at connecting to an STM8 chip.
